# move files to a linux guest vm on vmware using virtual floppy image of vmrc

Tags: vmware, suse, floppy

Consider a situation where I need to copy a file into a linux VM running on Vmware with no network access (i.e can't SSH), but with VMRC access. As we need to support other kinds of virtualization providers / physical hardware like Dell / HP blade servers, we cannot deviate much from the overall flow (so not looking for alternative solutions of ISO, VMDK etc.)

The proposed approach currently is to use a raw img file, attach it as a virtual floppy drive to the linux guest VM using VMRC. Unfortunately the file does not turn up as an additional device/ no floppy device is visible on running lsblk. Linux: SUSE 5.14.21

Is there anything additional to be done on the linux server?

A similar approach worked with the same file while attaching to the ILO of HP blade server. The OS is not significantly different as well.

Comment: I don't know VMRC, and what I can find out is "it gives you shell access": so, can you just type in arbitrary commands in that shell? is it a "normal" shell from the guest operating system (say, bash, zsh?)